# how to get android on click listener to work despite nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, click

My project throws a nullpointerexception buy attempting invoke an onclicklistener on a null object. here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    buttonSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignin);
 buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonSignin.setOnClickListener(this);



    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));  //it is here where the error is
    }
  }
 public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
    }
    if (view == buttonSignin)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
}
```

and here is logcat

```
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication7.MainActivityOne.onCreate(MainActivityOne.java:53)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

and this is interesting because it worked perfectly for me yesterday but now it does not. what is wrong with the code?

Comment: It means one of the buttons is null. Post the xml to see if the ids and View types match

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: no, i have not solved it yet. when i put the new view.onclicklisteners it still returned a nullpointerexception. i think i may have to wipe my data

Comment: The error means one of the calls to get a button (`buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);`) is returning null, and when you go call `setOnClickListener` on it you get a NullPointerException. Post the entire activity (including imports) and the `activity_main` xml. It could be caused by 1) wrong imported `Button` type or 2) wrong id in `findViewById`

Answer (score -1):

You have to properly set the 'context' for the setOnClickListeners of your Buttons.
Try doing this way:

```
 buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               registerUser();
            }
        });

 buttonSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Also, you can use a more precise way to get the firebase authentication instance. As you are using email and password to login you can use the Firebase authentication's [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-taskauthresult-signinwithemailandpassword-string-email,-string-password).

From this, you can also access the user credentials which might be helpful in other instances of your app.